# API Server giving 401 error after login

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have successfully logged in to the API Server using following code in meteorjs

```
var request = Npm.require('request');
        request('http://api-server-link-here',

        {

            'auth' : {

                'user': 'username',
                'pass': 'password',
                'sendImmediately': false
            }

        }

        , function (error, response, body) {
         if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log(response);

        }
```

But after this login when i go for using search query using code below. I get Http Status 401 error.

```
var request = Npm.require('request');
         request("http://search-query-link-here",

         {

        //search query parameters are here

         },


         function(error,response,body){

        console.log(response);

         });
```

Can anybody please give me pointers of why this issue is happening. Or if this is possible that i get a working example here?

One more thing that needs to be told here is that I'm doing login with the help of digest authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, it's kind of hard to provide you with a working example for an unknown API.

But let's just try to sort it out. Logically, when you send your search query, you are supposed to identify yourself. Most of the public API servers use either tokens (most probably) or session cookies in order to authorize access to a resource. So, whenever you do your second (search) request, you have either provide a token or send a cookie you are getting  from the first (login) request.

Long story short, verify which mechanism is being used by the API server.

- if it's tokens: check the response body from the login request; most probably there will be an access token you'd send then in the `Authorization` header of your API calls: `headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ...'}` in your request options;
- if it's sessions: make sure you have the cookie jar enabled on login and you it for subsequent requests: https://github.com/mikeal/request#requestjar

Comment: Im doing login with the help of digest auth. So, what do you say about this now?

Comment: Is any example which does the same with digest auth?

Comment: It's fine with the digest auth, but most probably it's supposed to be used just once, on login, which you don't have any problems with anyways. For the search calls you are most probably supposed to send a token/cookie you are getting as a result of your digest auth.

Comment: it seems like really helpful i will check and respond u back here.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me. My problem has been solved. Actually i then used cookie which was sent back to me by the server.

Comment: @Ronio Glad I could help. Please consider accepting the answer (checkbox on the left) and/or marking it helpful (arrow up) in order to improve your reputation and the quality of the StackOverflow knowledge base.